# Parse not enabling local datastore

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I know there is a ton of people posting this error here on stack overflow but with all the help that there is here I could not solve my problem.

```
10-23 00:22:15.858 19723-19723/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.laiq.laiq/com.laiq.laiq.UI.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: `Parse#enableLocalDatastore(Context)` must be invoked before `Parse#initialize(Context)`
10-23 00:22:15.858 19723-19723/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
10-23 00:22:15.858 19723-19723/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
10-23 00:22:15.858 19723-19723/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
10-23 00:22:15.858 19723-19723/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
10-23 00:22:15.858 19723-19723/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-23 00:22:15.858 19723-19723/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
10-23 00:22:15.858 19723-19723/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5373)
10-23 00:22:15.858 19723-19723/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-23 00:22:15.858 19723-19723/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-23 00:22:15.858 19723-19723/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
10-23 00:22:15.858 19723-19723/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
10-23 00:22:15.858 19723-19723/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: `Parse#enableLocalDatastore(Context)` must be invoked before `Parse#initialize(Context)`
10-23 00:22:15.858 19723-19723/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.parse.Parse.enableLocalDatastore(Parse.java:68)
10-23 00:22:15.858 19723-19723/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.laiq.laiq.UI.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
10-23 00:22:15.858 19723-19723/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
10-23 00:22:15.858 19723-19723/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
10-23 00:22:15.858 19723-19723/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
10-23 00:22:15.858 19723-19723/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442) 
10-23 00:22:15.858 19723-19723/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156) 
10-23 00:22:15.858 19723-19723/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351) 
10-23 00:22:15.858 19723-19723/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
10-23 00:22:15.858 19723-19723/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211) 
10-23 00:22:15.858 19723-19723/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5373) 
10-23 00:22:15.858 19723-19723/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
10-23 00:22:15.858 19723-19723/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
10-23 00:22:15.858 19723-19723/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020) 
10-23 00:22:15.858 19723-19723/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
```

I created the ParseApplication class but:

1. ParseCrashReport.enable(this) - cannot resolve
2. Even commenting the crash report the problem seems to continue

ParseApplication.class

```
public class ParseApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    ParseCrashReporting.enable(this);
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
    Parse.initialize(this, "xxx", "xxx"); --> my keys ofc
}

}
```

Anyone had this problem?

The app crashes right at start.

Comment: `{ ... .MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 'Parse#enableLocalDatastore(Context)' must be invoked before 'Parse#initialize(Context)'` looks like you are initializing Parse in your `MainActivity` as well? .. since your posted code looks correct, did you update your manifest to let it know that it should use `ParseApplication`?

Comment: `onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)` on line 37 to be exact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your crash report reveals that you are calling `Parse.enableLocalDatastore(Context)` in your MainActivity on line 37:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: `Parse#enableLocalDatastore(Context)` must be invoked before `Parse#initialize(Context)`
10-23 00:22:15.858 19723-19723/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.parse.Parse.enableLocalDatastore(Parse.java:68)
10-23 00:22:15.858 19723-19723/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.laiq.laiq.UI.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
```

All Parse initialization must happen in an extension of `Application` i.e. in your case `ParseApplication`.

Assuming `ParseApplication` is correctly added to your manifest, all you need to do is remove the `Parse.*` code in `onCreate()` of `MainActivity`.

Comment: That's it, simple answer that I wasn't able to find elsewhere, thumbs up!

Comment: What about the crash report? @cYrixmorten

Comment: Should be fine according to https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#crash-reporting. I have very minor experience with it, tried it briefly but ended up sticking with Crashlytics.